# Subgradient of Entropy

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, subgradient

If $(X,\Sigma\,u)$ is a finite measurable space, define the map 
$$
\begin{aligned}
X& \rightarrow (-\infty,\infty)\\
T(f)&\triangleq \int_{x \in X} f \log(f)\nu(dx),
\end{aligned}
$$
where $X\subset L^1(\nu)$ is defined by
$$
X\triangleq \left\{
f \in L^1(\nu) : f>0 \nu-a.e. \& T(f)<\infty
\right\}
.
$$
How can we compute the subgradient of $f$ on its domain.

Comment: There seems to be some typos in your question. In particular, the left-hand side of the second line of the displayed formula should be something like $T(f)$ if you would call the functional $T$. Moreover, I do not think that your functional is well defined on all of $L^1(\nu)_+$. In fact, if $f$ has a very sharp singularity, which is 'merely' integrable, $f \, \log(f)$ might fail to be integrable.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, hopefully this makes the question easier to answer.

Comment: I would guess that the subdifferential $\partial T(f)$ is nonempty iff $t \in L^\infty(\nu)$ and in this case $\partial T(f) = \{ 1+\log(f) \}$.

Comment: I obtained that $1+log(f)\in \partial T(f)$ also, but how to show that it is non-empty iff $f \in L^{\infty}$?

Comment: Did you try to show that $g \in \partial T(f)$ implies $g = 1 + \log(f)$? Then, $f \in L^\infty$ would follow, since $g \in L^\infty$.

Comment: You're right, this part is easy to do.  Thanks gerw :)